# Removed Nvidia Driver and now can't boot

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, re-installation

I have an older Gateway 510x and I recently installed a GeForce 6200 card and upgraded fine to 11.10.  However due to hibernate and wakeup problems and indication's that this could be due to the Nvidia driver, I, in my infinite wisdom, removed the driver and am now dead in the water - won't boot.  I can get to the Grub splash screen (I also have a MS Windows  7 partition).

How do I reinstall the driver if I can't boot?  I can come up with my 11.04 live CD.  I am not expert at this and am 70 years old so complete explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your problem is not booting, but your display driver not showing correctly your screen. If you're sure that this is not the case, disregard my answer.

If you reset your graphic configuration ubuntu should be able to reconfigure all display settings using the default driver.

After grub, press ctrl+alt+f4 to open a terminal. Login and then type *sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf* (please note the uppercase X); you will be asked to put your password again. Once the command is done, reboot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, nvidea drivers typically rewrite your kernel to include their modules. Reinstalling your kernel is a simple (brutish) way to "remove" the nvidea drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already fixed this, but if not, I believe you can rerun the portion of the install that configures the drivers with the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

which will walk you through the setup steps again.
To get to a command line where you can type this either select the recovery mode boot from the grub menu, or, if you are already booted but only see a black screen, you can likely switch to another terminal session by the key combination:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Note: Normally the standard graphics display is reached by:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

and others CLI are found on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

More info on 
http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/article/how_to_fix_your_computers_graphics_with_dpkg-reconfigure